Reshape wide to long using common prefix for group of varables
Here is how my data looks like:
# Example data. Lots of more variables liks x_ and y_
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), x_num = c(9,8,7), y_num = c(6,5,4), 
                 x_text_long = c("a","b","c"), y_text_long = c("d","e","f"), 
                 z = c(T,F,F))

Here is the desired output:
# Long
target <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), type = c("x","y","x","y","x","y"), 
                     num = c(9,6,8,5,7,4), text_long = c("a","d","b","e","c","f"),
                     z = c(T,T,F,F,F,F))

So, this is a wide to long conversion, with a unique aspect: some variable have two measures, prefixed with x_ and y_. It is enough then to create one variable "type" which specifies the measure, for all the variables. Also, the rest of the variable name should be part of the name of another variable, which contain the values.
So x_name = 5 should result in type=x and name = 5.
And this should of course respect the other variables with are unique, like id and z.
I've been looking at this page, and my two unsuccessful attempts are:
# This can do one (x,y) pair at a time, not efficient.
df[c("x_num","y_num")] %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `x_num`:`y_num`, 
    names_to = "type",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(type=substring(type,1,1))

# Not desired output
reshape(df,
        direction = "long",
        varying = list(names(df)[2:5]),
        v.names = "values",
        idvar = c("id"),
        timevar = "type")

I do not use data.table, so rather would use dataframes. Any ideas?

Use pivot_longer and having names_to >1, then .value in names_to "indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding values_to entirely. "
Edit, swapping x_text for x_text_long and swap from names_sep to names_pattern and a fun regex pattern.
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), x_num = c(9,8,7), y_num = c(6,5,4), 
             x_text_long = c("a","b","c"), y_text_long = c("d","e","f"), 
             z = c(T,F,F))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x_") | starts_with("y_"), 
               names_to = c("type", ".value"), 
               #names_sep = "_")
               names_pattern = "(.)_(.*)")

# A tibble: 6 × 5
     id z     type    num text_long 
  <dbl> <lgl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     1 TRUE  x         9 a    
2     1 TRUE  y         6 d    
3     2 FALSE x         8 b    
4     2 FALSE y         5 e    
5     3 FALSE x         7 c    
6     3 FALSE y         4 f  

